# Is "Do you know some writers?" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

Is "Do you know some writers?" grammatical? I mean, does that mean do you know a number of writers that isn't a few nor a lot but some? Is there ever used or could it be in that sense?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

> Do you know some writers?

could be used in that way, and is not ungrammatical. It is slightly ambiguous, in that "some" can be taken in any of several ways, and this sentence does not particularly indicate any of them more than any other. It could mean "more than one" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know some writers?

Yes, some means a number of, but not a large number of. The sentence is grammatical.

Generally, you use "any" in questions and negative sentences as follows:

Do you know any writers?

But sometimes when you think that the answer will be positive, we can use "some" in an interrogative sentence.